# Solutions for cron jobs in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to log some data daily, automatically in my rails app. I was wonder if anyone knows a good solution for this? I found https://github.com/javan/whenever, but I wanted to make sure I knew of all the options before I chose.

Thanks!

Elliot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really like whenever - it's a great Gem and I have used it in production.

There is also a good Railscasts episode about it:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll def give it a shot!